# Como passar dados de uma tabela para outra com checkbox usando o Angular?

Tags: angular

Meu problema é o seguinte: passar os itens selecionados de uma tabela, por checkbox, para uma outra tabela. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Muito obrigado!

Atualmente eu tenho uma tabela que carrega as informações do banco de dados, e gostaria de pegar essas informações e transferir alguns campos dessa tabela para outra, só que utilizando o checkbox para dizer quais linhas vou transferir.

Estou utilizando o Angular para desenvolver o front-end.

Gostaria de saber como faço para transferir essas informações.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para transferir as informações das linhas selecionadas da primeira tabela para a segunda, você pode seguir os seguintes passos:

Adicione um checkbox a cada linha da tabela, de modo que o usuário possa selecionar as linhas que deseja transferir.

Crie um array que irá armazenar os itens selecionados pelo usuário. Esse array pode ser inicializado como vazio, e ser atualizado sempre que o usuário marcar ou desmarcar um checkbox.

Crie uma função que será chamada sempre que o usuário marcar ou desmarcar um checkbox. Essa função deve adicionar ou remover o item correspondente do array de itens selecionados, dependendo do estado do checkbox.

Crie uma função para transferir os itens selecionados para a segunda tabela. Essa função deve percorrer o array de itens selecionados e adicionar cada um deles à segunda tabela.

Adicione um botão de "transferir" na primeira tabela, que chamará a função de transferência quando for clicado.

Voce pode usar a biblioteca Angular Material para criar as tabelas e os checkboxes, ou criar os componentes manualmente usando o Angular.

Exemplo de como fazer isso usando o Angular Material:

Adicione o Angular Material à sua aplicação, seguindo as instruções em https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started.

No template da sua componente, adicione uma tabela usando o componente mat-table e um checkbox em cada linha da tabela usando o componente mat-checkbox. Atribua um valor booleano à propriedade checked do checkbox, para indicar se ele está marcado ou não.

No componente, crie um array para armazenar os itens selecionados e inicialize-o como vazio. Atribua esse array à propriedade dataSource da tabela.

Adicione um event binding para o evento change do checkbox, para chamar uma função que atualiza o array de itens selecionados sempre que o usuário marca ou desmarca um checkbox.

Adicione um botão de "transferir" e crie uma função que percorre o array de itens selecionados e adiciona cada um deles à segunda tabela.

Espero que isso ajude! Se você tiver mais dúvidas, não hesite em perguntar.